# How to get drive letter returned as a string?

Tags: windows, rust, path

I'm struggling to get a string of the prefix of a path.  All I want to do is get the `"D:"` from the string `"D:\Household\Internet\September_2022_Statement.pdf"`.

If I follow the example for `std:path:Component` in [here](http://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/std/path/enum.Component.html), I can see the value I want but don't know how to get to it.

The code I am running is:

```
let filepath = "D:\\Household\\Internet\\September_2022_Statement.pdf";
let path = Path::new(filepath);
let components = path.components().collect::<Vec<_>>();
for value in &components {
  println!("{:?}", value);
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Prefix(PrefixComponent { raw: "D:", parsed: Disk(68) })
RootDir
Normal("Household")
Normal("Internet")
Normal("September_2022_Statement.pdf")
```

How do I get the raw value `"D:"` from `Prefix(PrefixComponent { raw: "D:", parsed: Disk(68) })`?

Comment: Can you provide more context as to what the result will be used for/what the possible inputs are? It’s possible to hardcode the single case of extracting things from `Prefix`, but that won’t be a complete answer if you’re interested in, for example, the other cases listed in [`Path::has_root`’s documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.has_root).

Comment: Is you search for `PrefixComponent` in the documentation, it has [an example that perfectly matches what you need](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.PrefixComponent.html#examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Samathingamajig and @PitaJ, I was able to achieve what I needed.  Obviously, I am a Rust newbie so I'm sure there is a cleaner way of doing this, but combining the help suggested, this works for me:

```
let filepath = "D:\\Household\\Internet\\September_2022_Statement.pdf";
let path = Path::new(fileName);
  let components = path.components().collect::<Vec<_>>();
  let mut os_string = OsString::new();
  match path.components().next().unwrap() {
    Component::Prefix(prefix_component) => {
      os_string = prefix_component.as_os_str().into();
    }
    _ => todo!()
  }

  println!("{}", os_string.to_str().unwrap());
```

Resulting output:

```
D:
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like components is an iterator of instances of the [`Component`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/enum.Component.html) enum, which is declared as

```rs
pub enum Component<'a> {
    Prefix(PrefixComponent<'a>),
    RootDir,
    CurDir,
    ParentDir,
    Normal(&'a OsStr),
}
```

Since you know that the drive is a `Prefix`, you can test for that.

```rs
let filepath = "D:\\Household\\Internet\\September_2022_Statement.pdf";
let path = Path::new(filepath);
let components = path.components().collect::<Vec<_>>();
for value in &components {
  if let std::path::Component::Prefix(prefixComponent) = value {
    return Some(value.as_os_str());
    // instead of returning you could set this to a mutable variable
    // or you could just check the first element of `components`
  }
}
None // if this were a function that returned Option<String>
```

The example from the [Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.PrefixComponent.html#examples) is

```rs
use std::path::{Component, Path, Prefix};
use std::ffi::OsStr;

let path = Path::new(r"c:\you\later\");
match path.components().next().unwrap() {
    Component::Prefix(prefix_component) => {
        assert_eq!(Prefix::Disk(b'C'), prefix_component.kind());
        assert_eq!(OsStr::new("c:"), prefix_component.as_os_str());
    }
    _ => unreachable!(),
}
```

Comment: field `raw` of `PrefixComponent` is private, you need `.as_os_str()` instead

Comment: @PitaJ updated; i didn't even know that rust had private fields until now